# Initializing a boolean on a form object that can be changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form object that I want to have an `enabled` field on which can be true or false depending on other logic in my project, how do I initialize something like that in the form object class? I have something like this...

```
 attr_accessor :enabled

        def initialize
          self.enabled = enabled
```

But I know this is incorrect.

And then in another spot in my code I want to do something like this

```
if something
        form_object.enabled
elsif something_else
        !form_object.enabled
end
```

Setting that `enabled` flag to the appropriate state so that I can use it for later

**Edit: adding more info**

The place where I want to put this `enabled` variable is in a helper Ruby Class I have

```
module Blah
  module Type
    module Mixins
      module CallToActionHelper

        attr_accessor :enabled


        def initialize(cta_use: nil, cta: nil)
          self.cta_type = cta_type
          self.cta_token = create_cta_token
          self.enabled = enabled
```

And then I have different ActiveRecord models for each type of call to action I have. They all also use the same controller, and the controller is the place where that `enabled` variable will be set depending on a hidden field in my params.

```
def populate_form_object(form_params, form_token)
      cta_use = set_call_to_action_use(cta_use_id: form_params['cta_use_id'], cta_type_key: form_params['cta_type_key'], cta_id: form_params['cta_id'])
      cta_type = CallToActionType.find_by_key(form_params['cta_type_key'])
      form_object = cta_type.get_type_form(cta_use: cta_use)
      form_object.cta_token = form_token

      form_object.enabled(params["call_to_action_use_#{form_token}_enabled"])
      # if params["call_to_action_use_#{form_token}_enabled"]
      #   form_object.enabled = true
      # elsif params["call_to_action_use_#{form_token}_enabled"] == 'false'
      #   form_object.enabled = false
      # else
      #   form_object.enabled = true
      # end


      return form_object
    end
```

You can see the code I've commeneted out where I tried to set this enabled field.

The above method, `populate_form_object` gets called on a save.

Comment: As a note, there's no need to include brackets on a method definition which has no arguments. `def initialize` is traditionally how that's expressed.

Comment: Instead of an accessor method, why not make a method with the same name? Or are you looking to be able to reset this even if it's assigned to something by default?

Comment: I'll be setting the state of `enabled` based off of a hidden field in my params. Could I just pass that hidden field into an `enabled` method in my form object?

Comment: The first thing here is to figure out what part of your code should be responsible for handling that. It might not be the model you're talking about here, as it doesn't need to know the origin of that value. For example, the controller might populate this once. I'm not entirely sure how this might be used, so it's hard to say what's best. Is this a regular Ruby object or an ActiveRecord model?

Comment: it's a helper model that umbrellas a group of ActiveRecord models

Comment: Still not sure what you mean. Can you create a minimal example that demonstrates what you're trying to do? This code is incomplete.